# Simple cross browser draw javascript library

Tags: javascript, draw

We are building a web app library which need draw some polyline/polygon/circle/rectange.

Also we want these vectors can be edited.

So I wonder if there is a cross browser draw library can be imported to our codes?

I know Raphael,however I think it is too strong,I mean there are too many features we do not need.

Also we found [this](http://www.walterzorn.de/en/jsgraphics/jsgraphics_e.htm),it render the vector using divs pixel by pixed. But we think the effect is not good.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Stick to Raphael. It has even support for older IE versions.

Comment: Maybe take a look at kineticJs: http://www.kineticjs.com/docs/symbols/Kinetic.php. Never tried it before but seems promising.

Comment: @nebulousGirl:It seems that it is based on html canvas,we have to support ie7+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally agree with Sirko's comment, stick to Raphael. There's nothing quite like it when it comes to cross-browser compatibility. Other than that, you could take a look at John Resig's [port of the procressing library](http://processingjs.org/) (which is a pretty mature visualization language).

Comment: For Raphael,we think that it is high weight. In fact,we only need to support ie7+.

Comment: @hguser Trust me, give Raphael a try, you won't regret it. I've done a couple of projects with it and have yet to find a better API for drawing in the browser.